# Asp.Net Mvc 4 JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I wrote this code,

```
public JsonResult Index(string query)
    {
        return Json(new object[] { "id", "text"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And result,

```
["id","text"]
```

But I want to look like below,

```
[{"value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"}]
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an anonymous object with the properties...

```
return Json(new object[] { new { value = 1, text = "Amsterdam" } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or create a class to return a strongly typed array...

```
private class City {
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

// ...

return Json(new City[] { new City { value = 1, text = "Amsterdam" } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```